# watch OS3 , UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities issue during ITC review

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-watch, watch, watchos-3

During testflight review, I run into the following issue:

> From Apple
>   2. 3 PERFORMANCE: ACCURATE METADATA Performance - 2.3
>
> We were unable to install the app extension on an Apple Watch running
>   OS3. The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in
>   such a way that the app will not install on an Apple Watch running
>   OS3.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key to verify that it
>   contains only the attributes required for your app features or the
>   attributes that must not be present on the device. Attributes
>   specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are required
>   and false if they must not be present on the device.

Now, my app is pretty much the Xcode example project for Watch OS3, I have not meddled with the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in any way.

In fact, neither the 'Watch App' nor the 'Watch App Extension' target even have an entry for 'UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities', only the iOS main target has the entry:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
```

App installs fine on watches with Watch OS3 too, when suppling it to devices via Xcode directly.

Comment: Same here, any news with this?

Comment: I ended up removing the 'armv7' from the device capabilities of the iOS target and it was accepted.
It shouldn't really matter, as it's only the setting for the iOS part but for some reason it was accepted afterwards :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up removing the 'armv7' from the device capabilities of the iOS target and it was accepted.
It shouldn't really matter, as it's only the setting for the iOS parent app but for some reason it was accepted afterwards :/