# VPN app rejected due to The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key don’t allow to install on an Apple Watch

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I have developed an application for **VPN** in ios and which is configured in apple watch. Which is rejected twice due to the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in `info.plist`.

**Here is the apple rejection:**

> We were unable to install the app on Apple Watch. The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in info.plist is set in such a way that the app will not install on an Apple Watch.

**I have also tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40084919/6418697) but doesn't work.**

**Here is the attached screenshot of Rejection:**

[image]

Comment: what is the value of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in all your target info.plist file?

Comment: When I have submitted app first time it was "armv7", it was rejected. Then I have tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/40084919/6418697 and removed value "armv7", still rejected again.

Answer (score 4):

There was no problem related to **`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`** key in `info.plist` file.

In `info.plist` file, there were keys named **`LSApplicationCategoryType`** with an empty value and **`LSRequiresIPhoneOS`**. I have removed both keys from `info.plist` and application successfully approved by apple.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for the feedback, but so far we analysed that we are not limiting our application to specific OS / architecture. Even we don't have UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities set in any of targets, and we are able to install the app from same testflight build, could you please verify once at your end or else allow us to create exact scenario. Thank you

Replied this, and same build got approved

Answer (score 0):

This issue not only related with UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities. If you have any empty valued key in the info.plist, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple documentation is quite clear about this key ([UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uirequireddevicecapabilities)

> Important:
> Your app must include the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Information Property List file that you submit with your binary. For app updates, you can only maintain or relax capability requirements. Submitting an update with added requirements would prevent some customers who previously downloaded your app from running the update.

It would appear to be needed to make the AppStore work, so adding the key should be a solution. May also be worth looking at the other WatchOS keys listed on that page too.

There is also a key WKWatchOnly which is a boolean to indicate an app is for WatchOS only. If you set this key you should remove UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities and the App Store team should accept the app.